# XSD schema with choice

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I need to validate XML request data in below array:

```
<studyYear></studyYear>
<orgID></orgID>
<originID></originID>
<providerID></providerID>
<userOID></userOID>
```

Problem - I have to get either (`orgID`) or (`userOID`) or (`originID` and `providerID`) together. 'studyYear' will always be there.  How I can realise it? If need more information just write. I referenced this [link](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Needs_choice_inside_all) to use so as to try using `xs:choice` inside `xs:all` but could not get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XSD,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="r">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="studyYear" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element name="orgID" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="userOID" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="orginID" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="providerId" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

will require `studyYear` to be followed by one of the following cases,

- `orgID`, or
- `userOID`, or
- both `originID` and `providerID`

as requested.

Comment: Its cool! But if I add the optional `element` thats will work?

Comment: If you add which optional element where?

Comment: In first `sequence` like a studyYear. And one more question: `sequence` means strict order?

Comment: Yes, `studyYear` can be made optional.  Yes, `xs:sequence` means strict order.

Comment: Ok, probably I'll use it, but there is the same approach but avoiding strict order?

Comment: `xs:all` is for no order, but it cannot contain `xs:choice`.